# Warning: array_combine(): Both parameters should have an equal number of elements

Tags: php, arrays

I have a problem here in `array_combine()`

> Warning: array_combine(): Both parameters should have an equal number of elements in PATH on line X

This error gets display on the following line:

```
foreach(array_combine($images, $word) as $imgs => $w)
{
    //do something
}
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: Have you tried putting the same number of elements in both arrays?

Comment: the number of elements for each array should be equal for array_combine() to work

Comment: what I want to do is, for example the user mistakenly added a null value, how can I avoid having this error?

Comment: I mean error handling for array_combine() when the elements are not equal

Answer (score 25):

This error appears when you try to combine two arrays with unequal length. As an example:

```
Array 1: Array (A, B, C)     //3 elements
Array 2: Array (1, 2, 3, 4)  //4 elements
```

`array_combine()` can't combine those two arrays and will throw a warning.

---

There are different ways to approach this error.

You can check if both arrays have the same amount of elements and only combine them if they do:

```
<?php

    $arrayOne = Array("A", "B", "C");
    $arrayTwo = Array(1, 2, 3);

    if(count($arrayOne) == count($arrayTwo)){
        $result = array_combine($arrayOne, $arrayTwo);
    } else{
        echo "The arrays have unequal length";
    }

?>
```

You can combine the two arrays and only use as many elements as the smaller one has:

```
<?php

    $arrayOne = Array("A", "B", "C");
    $arrayTwo = Array(1, 2, 3);

    $min = min(count($arrayOne), count($arrayTwo));
    $result = array_combine(array_slice($arrayOne, 0, $min), array_slice($arrayTwo, 0, $min));

?>
```

Or you can also just fill the missing elements up:

```
<?php

    $arrayOne = Array("A", "B", "C");
    $arrayTwo = Array(1, 2, 3);

    $result = [];
    $counter = 0;

    array_map(function($v1, $v2)use(&$result, &$counter){
        $result[!is_null($v1) ? $v1 : "filler" . $counter++] = !is_null($v2) ? $v2 : "filler";     
    }, $arrayOne, $arrayTwo);

?>
```

> **Note:** That in all examples you always want to make sure the keys array has only unique elements! Because otherwise PHP will just overwrite the elements with the same key and you will only keep the last one.

Comment: can you please provide a sample?

Comment: Your solution proved to be the one which worked for me - array_map did the job!

Answer (score -2):

You can use **array_merge** instead of **array_combine**

Example:

```
array_merge($myFirstArray, $mySecondArray);
```

Comment: You do understand what `array_combine` does, and how it's different from `array_merge`?  https://www.php.net/array_combine