# PHP Warning: array_combine(): Both parameters should have an equal number of elements

Tags: opencart2.x

I am getting warning on link_footer page in admin panel.

> Error
>
> Warning: array_combine(): Both parameters should have an equal number
>   of elements in admin\model\design\links_footer.php on line 69.

I am trying to solve it but i can't. so please help me to solve this warning.

Because of this warning i can't give links to the footer.

Please help me to solve this problem.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Warning: array\_combine(): Both parameters should have an equal number of elements](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19394980/warning-array-combine-both-parameters-should-have-an-equal-number-of-element)

Answer (score 0):

Open the file mentioned in error message, find line 69 and you'll find array_combine() function with 2 arrays in it (for example, $array1 and $array2). Add this:

```
var_dump($array1);
var_dump($array2);
exit;
```

BEFORE this function and run the script. You'll see contents of these 2 arrays. Make sure they both have equal number of values and if they don't try to figure out the root of the problem. You need to know some PHP though.