# Combine 2 non equal arrays into multi dimensional array

Tags: php, arrays

I have 2 arrays:

first[]:

```
Array
(
[First / Building] => code 100
[Second - Closed and Covered Cans] => code 200
)
```

second[]:

```
Array
(
[0] => 1,000.00
[1] => 2,000.00
[2] => 3,000.00
)
```

My desired out will be something like this :

final[]

```
Array
(
    [First / Building] => code 100
        (
            [0] => 1,000.00
        )

    [Second - Closed and Covered Cans] => code 200
        (
            [0] => 2,000.00
        )

)
```

(leave the [2] => 3,000.00 unmatched in this case)

If first[] count is > second[], let's say :

first[]

```
Array
(
[First / Building] => code 100
[Second - Closed and Covered Cans] => code 200
[Third - Closed and Covered Cans] => code 300
[Forth - Closed and Covered Cans] => code 400
)
```

second[]

```
Array
(
[0] => 1,000.00
[1] => 2,000.00
[2] => 3,000.00
)
```

My desired output :

final[]

```
Array
(
    [First / Building] => code 100
        (
            [0] => 1,000.00
        )

    [Second - Closed and Covered Cans] => code 200
        (
            [0] => 2,000.00
        )
     [Third - Closed and Covered Cans] => code 300
        (
            [0] => 3,000.00
        )
     [Forth - Closed and Covered Cans] => code 400
        (
        ) 
)
```

(leave the forth with no value in this case)

All the time pair the values from first array with the ones from second array. I tryed with array_combine(), but that isn't viable since they have different count.

Comment: Your desired result is not a valid array. An array element can't be both a string `code 100` and also an array.

Comment: Maybe it should be something like `"First / Building" => ['code' => 'code 100', 'price' => "1,000.00" ]`

Comment: may be of use: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19394980/warning-array-combine-both-parameters-should-have-an-equal-number-of-element

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`array_combine` is not useful because you don't have an array of keys. Your `first` array is already an associative array, and you want the result to have the same keys.

Use a `foreach` loop to go through the first array, while you increment a variable to get the index in the second array.

```
$final = [];
$i = 0;
foreach ($first as $key => $code) {
    $final[$key] = ["code" => $code, "price" => $second[$i]];
    $i++;
}
```