# Laravel Exception: Both parameters should have an equal number of elements

Tags: php, laravel

I'm new to laravel, and I'm making an app that need a .CSV data to be imported into the database, the data has been succesfully imported however i faced this issue :

`ErrorException array_combine(): Both parameters should have an equal number of elements`

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Accounts;
class AccountController extends Controller
{
    public function show(){
        return view ('upload');
    }
    public function store(Request $request){


        $file = $request->file('upload-file');
        $csvData = file_get_contents($file);

        $rows = array_map("str_getcsv", explode("\n", $csvData));
    // dd($rows);
        $header = array_shift($rows);
//    dd($header);
        foreach ($rows as $row) {

            $row = array_combine($header, $row);
            if (count($header) != count($row)) {
                continue;
              }
            set_time_limit(0);
            Accounts::create([
                'AccountClass' => $row['Classe'],
                'AccountNumber' => $row['Compte'],
                'AccountDesc' => $row['Desc'],
                'active' => 1,
            ]);
        }

        return view ('home');

    }

}
```

would you point me to the right direction thank you in advance

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Warning: array\_combine(): Both parameters should have an equal number of elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19394980/warning-array-combine-both-parameters-should-have-an-equal-number-of-element)

Comment: Put `count($header) != count($row) ` part before doing array_combine() and dump both of them to see the difference

Answer (score 1):

This error appears when you try to combine two arrays with unequal length.

```
$arr1 = ["a", "s", "d"];
$arr2 = [1, 2, 3];

if(count($arr1) == count($arr2)){
    $result = array_combine($arr1, $arr2);
} else{
    echo "Error array combine";
}
```

Comment: i have first array   0 => "1"
  1 => "1"
  2 => "COMPTES DE FINANCEMENT PERMANENT" and second array  array:3 [▼
  0 => "Classe"
  1 => "Compte"
  2 => "Desc"
] ;i guess they are equal

Comment: @anabel the problem is that you have duplicate values for keys, array_combine() tries to take values from the first array as keys and the values from the second array as values of the new array, i.e. tries to do this

1 => "Classe"
1 => "Compte"
"COMPTES DE FINANCEMENT PERMANENT" => "Desc"

The problem here is that you have duplicate keys (1 being duplicate)